# My Logitech MK320 keyboard doesn't type anything

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, keyboard

I have a wireless mouse/keyboard combo that worked fine until a few days ago. I used SCPToolkit to install my PS3 controller's drivers, and everything worked fine.

But then, I forgot where my controller was connected and installed the drivers in two USB ports. I might've installed the drivers in the port where the receiver for my wireless mouse and keyboard was, but I didn't think it would affect the performance.

The mouse works just fine and the keyboard won't type anything, however the "special function" keys still work, like the volume keys.

I already uninstalled SCPToolkit, and deleted the PS3 controller's drivers.

I need an external keyboard because my ESC key doesn't work on my laptop, which is a VAIO SVE11125CLB with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Drivers are not typically installed for a port, they are installed for a device. Can you open Device Manager and find the keyboard there? If it's there, open the properties dialog and tell us what drivers it is using.